# CALayer, NSTextView and scaling

Tags: cocoa, calayer, nstextview, nsscrollview

In my app I want to provide text scaling in layer backed NSTextView like Apple's TextEdit. I use analogue of it's [ScalingScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/TextEdit/Listings/ScalingScrollView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011741-ScalingScrollView_m-DontLinkElementID_29). Also I need to create some CALayer overlays on `self.window.contentView`. All is ok until I make `[self.window.contentView setWantsLayer:YES]`.

Before `[setWantsLayer:YES]`

[image]

After `[setWantsLayer:YES]`

[image]

I haven't any ideas how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been searching for the solution to the similar issue, too. Finally, I discovered that layer-backed views must be positioned on integral pixels and must not be positioned on subpixels.

E.g. if you dynamically calculate frame of layer-backed view

```
 NSMakeRect((self.frame.size.width - 350)/2, (self.frame.size.height - 150)/2, 350, 150)
```

you may encounter non-integral values, so you should do something like

```
 NSMakeRect(floor((self.frame.size.width - 350)/2), floor((self.frame.size.height - 150)/2), 350, 150)
```

Comment: God, you're great! Unfortunatelly, this question has lost it's actuality, but your solution so elegant. Thanks!